# General method to count number of ways a number N can be written as a product of k Integers

Tags: permutations, factoring

Is there a general method to count number of ways a number N can be written as a product of k Integers (positive or negative).

The specific question I encountered was to count in how many ways I can write 144 as a product of 3 positive integers and so I wonder if there is any general method. Like I know that $144 = 2^{4}3^{2}$ and so there would be $(4+1)(2+1) = 15$ factors in total but then how to count number of ways I can divide $144$ into product of three factors.

**Clarification**: Order of factors don't matter i.e. $1⋅12⋅1$ is same as $12⋅1⋅12$ and so on for other combinations. Also we consider 1 as a factor i.e. $1⋅12⋅12=144$ is to be considered.

Comment: To clarify, do order of factors matter?  Do you allow a factor of $1$?  Do you consider $12\cdot 12\cdot 1=144$ to be different than $12\cdot 1\cdot 12=144$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I guess that if the answer to either of these question is "no", we land in an inclusion-exclusion principle hell

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen well, that or a horrible generating function using multiple variables that is in reality no better than brute force.

Comment: @JMoravitz Order of factors don't matter i.e. $12⋅1 = 1⋅12$ and $1$ is allowed in factors i.e. $12⋅12⋅1$ is considered. I have edited my question to clarify the same.

Comment: In that case, the answer by Hagen below is incorrect.  His answer assumed that order does matter.

Comment: I have removed the acceptance. Also I think 1 is not considered as a factor in Hagen's solution?

Answer (score 5):

If  the prime factortization of $N$ is $$N=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}$$ with $a_i\in\Bbb N_0$ (and distict primes $p_i$), then to write $N$ as product of $k$ factors, we need do write each $a_i$ as sum of $k$ non-negative integers (which are then the exponents of $p_i$ in the corresponding factor). Using "stars and bars", we conclude that there are
$$ \prod_i {a_i+k-1\choose k-1}$$
ways to write $N$ as product of $k$ positive integers.

If we allow negative factors, we can pick $k-1$ signs and then the last sign is determined, so now we count 
$$ 2^{k-1}\prod_i {a_i+k-1\choose k-1}$$
ways.

Comment: Can you look at the clarifications I made in the question as pointed out by @JMoravitz about considering $1$ and about order of the factors.